Off-state output terminal voltage in a MOSFET
When choosing a photorelay, I came across the parameter "off-state output terminal voltage". I understand (sort of) how the e-MOSFET transistors used in this relay work. I understand that at a voltage of Vgs>Vt, the transistor will conduct and that at a voltage lower the transistor is non-conducting.
What does off-state output terminal voltage mean in this case?
For example, in this photorelay, the "Operating Voltage Range" is indicated, which, as I understand it, is the parameter necessary for me to select a relay
I also read the articles on one site. Based on this question we can say that in the figure of the article "MOSFET Characteristics Curves" off-state output terminal voltage is the voltage Vdd = Vds= Voff from the datasheet of the photorelay?
It is necessary to select such a relay for switching a signal with parameters of +-20 V and a current of ~0.1 A.

We don't use pneumatic/hydraulic valve terminology in EE so, if a transistor is "closed" it is activated or conducting and, if a transistor is "open", we assume you mean "open circuit" or non-conducting.

'Off State Terminal Voltage' means the voltage you can apply to the terminals when the switch is off.
In the case of your first link to the TLP202A, it has 60 V as an absolute maximum (expect damage if you exceed this), and 48 V as the recommended maximum voltage (a reasonable voltage to design to, allowing for possible instrument error and small fluctuations).
It means exactly the same thing as 'Operating Voltage Range' in your second link to the PVG612. Unusually, this data sheet does not distinguish between Absolute Max, and Recommended Max, though it does give figures of 60 V and 48 V in various places in the data sheet.

Thanks for your reply. Could you also explain how the +-20 V and a current of ~0.1 A current signal will be switched through an complementary pair  of transistors used in the photorail, unfortunately I do not quite understand

@Marl0s it depends what you mean by 'explain'. It seems to be obvious from the circuit diagram. For details of the internal semiconductor behaviour, I don't find Fermi levels, electrons and holes that instructive, so tend to resort to 'if it happens, it must be true',
